# The stylesheet "path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome-min.css" didn't load because its MIME Type, text/html, is not text/css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a React App deployed with Heroku,

On Google Chrome, everythings works fine, but in Mozilla Firefox, I have the error in title :

```
The stylesheet "path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome-min.css" didn't load because its MIME Type, text/html, is not text/css
```

Here's the part involved in my index.html

```
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="/path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
/>
```

Do you know what I have to change please ?

Comment: Can you load the stylesheet into Firefox (by typing the full path into the location bar)? If this works, what does the browser say the file type is? (Right-click, view page info.)

Comment: it's ok now thanks

Answer (score 0):

"/path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" is a placeholder that you need to change with the current path to font-awesome in your project.

It's different for each project, but if you installed with NPM maybe it's something like:

`node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`

Comment: so you're telling em that icons are not supposed to work like that? because they're working